# ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype

Tags: python, php, html, json, intellij-idea

```
async def uuid(ctx, *, message): # b'\xfc'
await ctx.message.delete()
q = urlencode({"q":message})
async with aiohttp.ClientSession()as session:
    async with session.get(f'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{q}') as resp:
         r = await resp.json(content_type='custom/type')
await ctx.send(r["id"])
```

I keep getting this error I've tried many ways by using application/json but i keep getting the same error

```
[ERROR]: Command raised an exception: ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: ', url=URL('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/q=5929')
```

Comment: If you show us your code, there is every possibility someone can help you. But if you cant we cant, as we are not clairvoyant

Comment: By show us the code I mean copy/paste the text into the question and not a picture of the code

Comment: async def uuid(ctx, *, message): # b'\xfc'
    await ctx.message.delete()
    q = urlencode({"q":message})
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession()as session:
        async with session.get(f'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{q}') as resp:
             r = await resp.json(content_type='custom/type')
    await ctx.send(r["id"])

Comment: copy/paste the code INTO THE QUESTION using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61856664/edit) link Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: done, sorry im new

Comment: No probelm, we all start the same :)

Comment: You might like to TAG that language as well it does not look like PHP/HTML or JSON

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, the file is .py

Comment: can someone help